# javascript error in IE 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

This is throwing a js error in ie8, FF is good. any ideas?
This is line 1340

```
var cc_meth_cookie =$.cookie("cc_method");
```

This is line 1339 just in case...

```
$(Choose_PaymentMethodType(1));
```

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; Creative AutoUpdate v1.30.00)
Timestamp: Thu, 2 Sep 2010 17:15:41 UTC

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 1340
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: (deleted)

Comment: We're going to need to see what `Choose_PaymentMethodType` does.

Comment: make sure you're including jquery and jquery.cookie plugin.

Comment: Don't get excited it's just a variable name, lol

Comment: What a moron I am, forgot the cookie plugin. Interesting how it worked in FF though

Comment: You should add an answer yourself now and check that when it's possible; this way, we can see that this question no longer needs our attention. Thanks.

Comment: as @Jacon said, we would have needed a lot more info to figure out what was going on here - i.e. something nearer to a working example than 2 lines of code.  I suggest either deleting this question or editing your question and writing up a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a moron!!!!

LMAO

I forgot to load the cookie plugin,

Thx Marcel for reminding me of that fact!!!

Comment: I wasn't me who did that, but Sergei.